# How can I check if a UILabel's value is more than 0 in an if statement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

How can I check if a UILabel's value is more than 0 in an if statement?

I have tried the following code:

```
if(ArtCount.text.intValue > 0)
{
}
```

But it comes back with the following error:

```
2011-12-01 20:52:50.124 iDHSB[2955:707] -[UILabel isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a9860
2011-12-01 20:52:50.126 iDHSB[2955:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    
[UILabel isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a9860'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x323e28bf 0x35cfa1e5 0x323e5acb 0x323e4945 0x3233f680 0x3152b191 0x6cff3 0x316cf871 0x323e5814 0x323407e1 0x323403ff      
0x34767e5b 0x323e4ab3 0x3233f680 0x323e5814 0x323407e1 0x33dcb43d 0x33dde8dd 0x323b6b03 0x323b62cf 0x323b5075 0x323384d5 
0x3233839d 0x378b7439 0x315558e1 0x2d0f 0x2758)
terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
(gdb)
```

Comment: The above code is unlikely the cause of the above error. In the debugger, where does it actually crash? Where do you call `isEqualToString:` on a `UILabel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message:

```
[UILabel isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a9860
2011-12-01 20:52:50.126 iDHSB[2955:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    
[UILabel isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

indicates that the line that caused the exception was calling the method `isEqualToString` on an instance of `UILabel`, the provided code does not contain this method call.

Look for the statement that is calling `isEqualToString` on a `UILabel` instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([ArtCount.text intValue] > 0) {
  ...
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is 100% identical to the OP's code. Occasionally avoiding dot-notation like this is required when the compiler gets confused, but it couldn't have caused this particular runtime error.