# Why is my UILabel not recognising "isEqualToString:"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a UILabel's value is more than 0 in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348478/how-can-i-check-if-a-uilabels-value-is-more-than-0-in-an-if-statement)

Why is the following code not working?

```
    if([Period2 isEqualToString:@"PSHEEC"])
    {

        NSLog(@"TEST");

    }
```

I am getting this error:

> 2011-12-02 08:45:52.579 iDHSB[7605:707] -[UILabel isEqualToString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4884c50 2011-12-02
>   08:45:52.581 iDHSB[7605:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel
>   isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4884c50'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x323e28bf 0x35cfa1e5 0x323e5acb 0x323e4945 0x3233f680 0x3152b191 0x9c905 0x316cf871 0x323e5814
>   0x323407e1 0x323403ff 0x34767e5b 0x323e4ab3 0x3233f680 0x323e5814
>   0x323407e1 0x33dcb43d 0x33dde8dd 0x323b6b03 0x323b62cf 0x323b5075
>   0x323384d5 0x3233839d 0x378b7439 0x315558e1 0x2d77 0x27c0) terminate
>   called throwing an exception[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
>   (gdb)

Comment: print the period2 value you can check whether the string is correct or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is propably due to memory mamagement issues, the pointer of `Period2` is not pointing to you string any more and is now pointing to some label. Make sure you have retained it correctly.

On an other note, variable, properties, methods should not start with a capital, and if you label is a properties you should use `self.period2` .

Comment: But Period1 is an NSString... :S

Comment: Sorry mistype, re-read my question

Comment: Yes I understand, its a memory management error. See my answer i've rewritten it.

Comment: In given exception description, its clearly mentioned...Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4884c50' On that basis, Period2 is a UILabel not an NSString!

Answer (score 1):

if period2 is your label use...

```
[period2.text isEqualToString:@"PSHEEC"]
```

Comment: That's what the error is for though and the Period2 is my NSString for a UILabel...

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful

```
NSString *str = label.text;
if([str isEqualToString:@"PSHEEC"])
{
NSLog(@"Equal");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"Not Equal");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What is Period2? You can't test equivalence that way. If you want to test string equivalence, you need to do something like the following:

(assuming Period2 is an NSString)

```
if ([Period2 isEqualToString:@"PSHEEC]) {
    NSLog(@"They are equal.");
}
```

Comment: This was a legitimate answer but the question edits have made it irrelevant.